# Resolving Host in remotebuild on Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cordova

Went to Tools --> Options --> Tools for Apache Cordova --> iOS Configuration in Visual Studio on my Windows machine.

On my Mac Machine I ran `remotebuild certificates generate` and got back:

```
Enable remote iOS processing: True
Host: hostname
Port: 3000
Secure mode: True
Security PIN: 000000
```

(I replaced host and pin such that this question may be useful to others in the future).

In Visual Studio on my Windows machine I filled in my hostname, secure mode, pin, etc according to the remotebuild certificates above. I have also tried replacing hostname with my mac IP address.

I am getting the message `The host hostname could not be resolved`. However, when I go to my Mac machine and do `localhost:3000` I get a page saying

> Remote build Express server open for business on port 3000

and on my terminal, the server responds with `GET / 304 2.185 ms - -`, so I know the server is active. What is the solution to fixing this on the Visual Studio side?

Comment: When I use IP address rather than hostname, I get the error "An error occurred trying to acquire certificate from `https://IP_ADDRESS`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution : turns out my computers were on two different WiFi networks..